# Steering Behaviors in Discrete Space

Tags: movement, steering-behaviors

I'm interested in [Steering Behaviors by Craig W. Reynolds](https://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/) in a project but my agents are in a discrete grid (think Minecraft). Essentially all agents internally have continuous speed, accelerations and force vectors (first and second derivate vectors) but their positions are constrained to a grid and updated in fixed timesteps. How would I adapt a framework [like this one](https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/Steerio) in order for the agents to be on a grid on different cases:

1. The first and second continuous derivates are shared with the agent, positions are discrete.
2. The derivates are *NOT* shared, and have to be estimated
3. The action mappings are also required to be discrete (forward/back, left/right, rotate 90 ect)

Comment: How fast do your agents move in grid terms?

Comment: Let say the grid *G* has spacings of one meter and agent has an internal real speed of 5.2 m/s and the game world is updated every half second. Then on each update the agent would move 2.6 meters and would snap to the nearest coordinate in *G*. Then from an external viewer the estimated speed would be 4 - 6 m/s on *G*.